# How to simplify the formatting array list data in php API to feed React Native section list

Tags: php, arrays, react-native, api, react-native-sectionlist

Good day!
I am writing RestAPI using php. My team member is consuming the API using React-native, He requested that I should format the response in the Format bellow

```
{
        title: 'Class of 2007',
        data: [
            { id: 1, lastsName: 'Igbashio', firstName: 'Kalifort', middleName: 'Kashimana', email: 'igbashiokalifortkashimana@gmail.com', image: 'https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/young-student-caucasian-woman-isolated-white-background-pointing-side-present-product_1368-289762.jpg?w=740' },
            { id: 2, lastsName: 'Usman', firstName: 'Bello', middleName: '', email: 'usmanbello@gmail.com', image: 'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/waist-up-portrait-handsome-serious-unshaven-male-keeps-hands-together-dressed-dark-blue-shirt-has-talk-with-interlocutor-stands-against-white-wall-self-confident-man-freelancer_273609-16320.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1337949710.1669025188' },
            { id: 3, lastsName: 'Manasseh', firstName: 'Isa', middleName: '', email: 'manassehisa@gmail.com', image: 'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/young-attractive-handsome-guy-feels-delighted-gladden-amazed_295783-535.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1337949710.1669025188' }
        ]
    },
    {
        title: 'Class of 2008',
        data: [
            { id: 4, lastsName: 'Igbashio', firstName: 'Sansa', middleName: 'Sewuese', email: 'igbashiosansaswewuese@gmail.com', image: 'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/front-view-female-student-white-shirt-black-jacket-wearing-backpack-holding-files-with-copybooks-blue-wall-college-university-lessons_140725-43393.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1337949710.1669025188' },
            { id: 5, lastsName: 'Yusuf', firstName: "Sa'atu", middleName: '', email: 'yusufsaatu@gmail.com', image: 'https://img.freepik.com/free-photo/cheerful-muslim-woman_53876-14375.jpg?w=360&t=st=1669732335~exp=1669732935~hmac=9942e2842661b423d7686f2ba66d87b2b9485e95f438b415993b38e910203937' },
            { id: 6, lastsName: 'Rimamtse', firstName: 'Bleesing', middleName: 'Fxiafatirimam', email: 'rimamblessing@gmail.com', image: 'https://img.freepik.com/premium-photo/smiling-black-woman-striped-shirt-with-arms-crossed_33839-10129.jpg?size=626&ext=jpg&ga=GA1.2.1337949710.1669025188' }
        ]
    },
```

In order to use in react-native sectionList.
Below is how I achieved the task so far

```
$list = Members::where(function ($sql) use ($input) {
            if (isset($input["search"])) :
                return $sql->where('regNo', 'LIKE', $input["search"])->orWhere('lastsName', 'LIKE', $input["search"])
                    ->orWhere('firstName', 'LIKE', $input["search"])->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', $input["search"])
                    ->orWhere('phone', 'LIKE', $input["search"])->orWhere('gender', 'LIKE', $input["search"]);
            endif;
        })->orderBy('graduateYear', 'DESC')->orderBy('lastsName', 'ASC')->skip($input["start"])->take($input["length"])->get();
die(json_encode(formatMembers($list)));


private function formatMembers($list)
    {
        $json = array();
        $i = 0;
        $lastYear = null;
        foreach ($list as $x) {
            if (count($json) == 0) :
                $json[$i]["title"] = $x->graduateYear;
                $json[$i]['data'][] = array(
                    "id" => $x->id, "lastsName" => $x->lastsName, "firstName" => $x->firstName,
                    "middleName" => $x->middleName, "email" => $x->email, "image" => null
                );
                $lastYear = $x->graduateYear;
            else:
                if ($lastYear == $x->graduateYear) :
                    $json[$i]['data'][] = array(
                        "id" => $x->id, "lastsName" => $x->lastsName, "firstName" => $x->firstName,
                        "middleName" => $x->middleName, "email" => $x->email, "image" => null
                    );
                    $lastYear = $x->graduateYear;
                else :
                    $i++;
                    $json[$i]["title"] = $x->graduateYear;
                    $json[$i]['data'][] = array(
                        "id" => $x->id, "lastsName" => $x->lastsName, "firstName" => $x->firstName,
                        "middleName" => $x->middleName, "email" => $x->email, "image" => null
                    );
                    $lastYear = $x->graduateYear;
                endif;
            endif;
        }
        return $json;
    }
```

Bellow is the result of my implementation

```
[
        {
            "title": "2016",
            "data": [
                {
                    "id": 6,
                    "lastsName": "Igbashio ",
                    "firstName": "Sansa",
                    "middleName": "Seember",
                    "email": "sansaigbashio@Gmail.com",
                    "image": null
                },
                {
                    "id": 7,
                    "lastsName": "Usman",
                    "firstName": "Smith",
                    "middleName": "",
                    "email": "smithusman@Gmail.com",
                    "image": null
                }
            ]
        }]
```

My question is there a better way of achieving this?
considering when dealing with a large number of records or even a shorter method.
Any ideal will be welcome.
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use temporary first-level associative keys to assist in grouping.  When finished iterating, remove the first-level keys with `array_values()`;

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gBJWh))

```
$grouped = [];
foreach ($array as $obj) {
    sscanf($obj->graduateYear, 'Class of %d', $year);
    unset($obj->graduateYear);
    $grouped[$year]['title'] = $year;  // doesn't matter that this is overwritten over and over
    $grouped[$year]['data'][] = $obj;
}
var_export(array_values($grouped));
```

Please also heed the warning [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/74764961/2943403) regarding mutating objects inside of a foreach loop.

Comment: Thank you @mickmackusa. I tested your code but the title is always null and it's grouping it to the null title.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this code chunk:

```
                $json[$i]["title"] = $x->graduateYear;
                $json[$i]['data'][] = array(
                    "id" => $x->id, "lastsName" => $x->lastsName, "firstName" => $x->firstName,
                    "middleName" => $x->middleName, "email" => $x->email, "image" => null
                );
                $lastYear = $x->graduateYear;
```

The only difference between the cases seems to be that in some cases you add a `title` while in other cases you are not adding a title. So, instead of duplicating the whole code it makes more sense to do something like this:

```
if (!isset($json[$i])) {
    $json[$i] = [
        'title' => ($lastYear = $x->graduateYear),
    ];
}
/*Your template here*/
if ($lastYear !== $x->graduateYear) {
    $i++;
}
```

As it currently stands, you repeat your code thrice, so if there is any change needed on your template, then you will need to do it 3 times, which is a 3x increase in the labor necessary.

A further improvement would be to create a `function` that would receive some parameters and would create the object you are to assign as the data. This would make sure that your template will be reusable at other places if you have to use the same format at another API function as well.